# How to transfer a variable value from one function to anoter function?

Tags: javascript, html

Actually i want to transfer the value of my variable to another function in javascript. I tried many methods. In fact I search on stackoverflow but i didn't get correct output.

When i click on button show() function runs and form open

```
function show(){
 var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var id = target.id;

         var x = document.getElementById(id).parentElement.id; // I am  getting the value of 'x' when i alert it shows correct output
        //alert(x);

         $.ajax({
                url: 'php/retrieve_characters.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {},
                success: function(response) {

                    var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                     if(data!='') {      

                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        $('#0').attr('src',data[0].charac);
                        $('#1').attr('src', data[1].charac);
   });

                }
            }
        })


    }
```

Now when form opens i click a button which is in form and new function runs

```
  function setimage(){
       var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var id = target.id;



           $.ajax({
           url: 'php/retrieve_characters.php',
           type: 'post',
           data: {},
           success: function(response) {

           var data = $.parseJSON(response);
           if(data!='') {

           $.each(data, function(i, item) {

           var parent=document.getElementById("par1");
           var child = parent.lastElementChild;
           while (child) {
           parent.removeChild(child);
           child = parent.lastElementChild;
           }
           var li = document.createElement("img");

           li.setAttribute("id", "char"+id);
           li.setAttribute("src", data[id].charac);

           li.setAttribute("onclick", "show()");
            li.setAttribute("class", "imgs-thumbnail");
           parent.appendChild(li);


           });

           }
           }


           })
    }
```

In function setimage() i want the value of x which is in first function.
Remember one thing I don't want to call one function into another because in both functions i m retrieving data from database which will be messed up if both functions will be concatenated.

Comment: You could use X as a global variable. Or you make a class and wrapper both functions inside of it and make the **x** and attribute.

Comment: Since the ajax call has its own callback, you should be able to set the calling of the other function just under the ajax call, yet before the function closes.

Comment: Where does `setimage()` use `x`?

Comment: I did but it always gives 'undefined ' output

Comment: I used var x in setimage() but it was giving undefined output so i erased that portion

Comment: Where would it use it if it could?

Comment: Why does `show()` keep overwriting the `src` of the same two elements in a loop?

Comment: `if (data != '')` doesn't make sense. `data` is an array, not a string.

Comment: You should use `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax` calls, then jQuery will parse the JSON automatically for you.

Comment: Why doesn't the `$.each()` loop use `i` or `item`?

Comment: There is no problem in my json,Ajax... Everything is regarding the variable x in show() function